# Separate logs from Apache spark

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to have separate log files from workers, masters and jobs(executors, submits, don't know how call it). I tried configuration in `log4j.properties` like

```
log4j.appender.myAppender.File=/some/log/dir/${log4j.myAppender.FileName}
```

and than passing `log4j.myAppender.FileName` in `SPARK_MASTER_OPTS`, `SPARK_WORKER_OPTS`, `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` and `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`.

It works perfectly well with workers and masters but fails with executors and drivers. Here is example of how I use these:

```
./spark-submit ... --conf "\"spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=log4j.myAppender.FileName=myFileName some.other.option=foo\"" ...
```

I also tried putting `log4j.myAppender.FileName` with some default value in `spark-defaults.conf` but it doesn't work neither.

Is there some way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Logging for Executors and Drivers can be configured by `conf/spark-defaults.conf` by adding these entries (from my windows config)

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions  -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:/dev/programs/spark-1.2.0/conf/log4j-driver.properties
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:/dev/programs/spark-1.2.0/conf/log4j-executor.properties
```

Note that each entry above references a different `log4j.properties` file so you can configure them independently.