# Missing java system properties when running spark-streaming on Mesos cluster

Tags: spark-streaming, mesos

I submit a spark app to mesos cluster(running in cluster mode), and pass java system property through `"--drive-java-options=-Dkey=value -Dkey=value"`, however these system properties are not available at runtime, seems they are not set. `--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dkey=value"` doesn't work either

More details:
the command is

```
bin/spark-submit --master mesos://10.3.101.119:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --class ${classname} --driver-java-options "-Dconfiguration.http=http://10.3.101.119:9090/application.conf" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfiguration.http=http://10.3.101.119:9090/application.conf" ${jar file}
```

I have a two-node mesos cluster, one node both runs master and slave, and the other runs slave only. I submit the spark application on master node.

Internally, the application hopes to read a configuration file from java system property "configuration.http", if the property is not available, the application will load a default file from the root of the classpath. When I submit the application, from the logs, i saw the default configuration file is loaded.

And the actual command to run the application is

```
"sh -c '/home/ubuntu/spark-1.6.0/bin/spark-submit --name ${appName} --master mesos://zk://10.3.101.184:2181/mesos/grant --driver-cores 1.0 --driver-memory 1024M --class ${classname} ./${jar file} '"
```

from here you can see the system property is lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at [this blog post](http://progexc.blogspot.de/2014/12/spark-configuration-mess-solved.html) which recommends using an external properties file for this purpose:

```
$ vi app.properties
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions   -Dconfiguration.http=http://10.3.101.119:9090/application.conf
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions –Dconfiguration.http=http://10.3.101.119:9090/application.conf
```

Then try to run this via

```
bin/spark-submit --master mesos://10.3.101.119:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --class ${classname} —-properties-file app.properties ${jar file}
```

See

- [How to pass -D parameter or environment variable to Spark job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166667/how-to-pass-d-parameter-or-environment-variable-to-spark-job)
- [Separate logs from Apache spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449059/separate-logs-from-apache-spark)

Comment: Do I have to put that file to all of the nodes? We don't run HDFS, so I have to put copies of the properties file at a special path on all nodes?

Comment: My understanding is that the file only has to be present on the node where you execute `spark-submit`, but I haven't tried it...