# Sending extraJavaOptions for Spark 1.6.1 on mesos 0.28.2 in cluster mode

Tags: java, apache-spark, mesos

When I spark-submit an application to run with apache mesos,
it does not recognize the properties below at all and code returns null that reads them.

```
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dsome.url=http://some-url 
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dsome.url=http://some-url
```

[tried option here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872093/missing-java-system-properties-when-running-spark-streaming-on-mesos-cluster?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and still got no change in the result.

Any idea how to supply system properties in mesos.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? extraJavaOptions are typically used for JVM related parameters and they have specific names.

Comment: spark.driver.extraJavaOptions can be used to set and pass any System properties. In Yarn I am able to access it fine. It is just Mesos where I am experiencing this difficulty.